# Drupal 7 page by page links

Tags: drupal-7, view, hyperlink

I'm working on a drupal site, and what I'm wondering is, I have a site that will have a main navigation menu-bar at the top of the page.

Then, other then the front page, each page will have it's own set of links. Now these links will be duplicated across pages that relate to each other. So, I know essentially what I need to do is to create individual blocks of navigation and then control those based on the page but I don't know how to do that.

Can anyone explain what I would need to do for this to work? Tutorials or videos would be helpful.

Comment: The only way so far (which is messy) is to add blocks for the navigation and then in the 'Show only for pages' area I selected which pages to display it for. If anyone has any better ideas I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a taxonomy vocabulary containing all of the links.

Then add a **term reference** field to your page content type with checkboxes for the widget type.
Then when you edit the page you will be able to select any links that are needed for that page.

Control how these links are displayed on the page by looking at the **manage display** tab when editing the structure of the page content type.